# Python Spell Check Replace in Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a spell check function that takes a sentence or sentences as a list and then I have to go through the words and see if 1)they are in the wordList (it's a list of words from a Webster Dictionary) and if they are in the list print them or 2)if they're not in that wordList then I need to check to see if it's in this dictionary I created which has replacement words for commonly misspelled words: example- `{'cta':'cat','teh':'the'}` and if the word is in the key place in that dictionary I need to replace it with the correct spelling of it which is in the value place. My function is much longer than this but this is the portion I am struggling with-

separate is my original sentence that has been turned into a list of words, wordList is the list of words from the Webster Dictionary, and d is the dictionary which contains the commonly misspelled words and their replacement.

```
newList=[]
for line in separate:
    for word in line:
        if word in wordList:
            newList.append(word)
        elif word in d:
            for {i:c} in d:
                newList=newList.replace(i,c)
return newList
```

Answer (score 2):

Without any sample input to test, it seems you want something like this:

```
newList=[]
for line in separate:
    for word in line:
        if word in wordList:
            newList.append(word)
        elif word in d:
            newlist.append(d[word])
        else:
            # Skip the word?
            pass
return newList
```

**BONUS:** If you want to iterate over all keys and values in a dict, you can do it like this:

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    newList=newList.replace(key, value)
```

Comment: Regarding the "bonus": In Python 3, `iteritems` doesn't exist any more. Just use `items` directly, as it now returns a "view" object that is cheap to build and can be iterated over easily.